# Swift Comparing values in a single array

Tags: arrays, swift, ios8

Using swift in Xcode I have an array of float values '`IMProdArray`.'
I would like to determine a function that checks the values in the array to determine if any of the values are within 0.200 of each other.  If they are return 'false', if they aren't, return 'true'.

As a similar function I would also like to calculate the biggest distance between two values and return the halfway point value:  i.e.

In an array I have values:  `1, 3, 4, 10, 11, 12`

the largest gap between two values (if they are in order) is `4-10`.  The mid value of this is 7. So return 7.

A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for a solution, here's the solution (though I really shouldn't just be writing your code for you).

This works for an array sorted in ascending order (sort your array before using this code if it isn't already sorted):

```
var maxGap = -1
var maxGapIndex = -1
for i in [1..<IMProdArray.count] {
    let gap = IMProdArray[i] - IMProdArray[i-1]
    if gap <= 0.2 {
        // handle the values being within 0.2 of each other
    }
    if gap > maxGap {
        maxGap = gap
        maxGapIndex = i-1 // store the index of the first number
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the index of the gap from `maxGapIndex`. For your example, `maxGapIndex` will be 2, which is the index of **4** in your array.